# Merge duplicate entries in array of dict

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, dictionary, merge

I'm struggling with a recursive merge problem.

Let's say I have:

```
a=[{'name':"bob", 
    'age':10, 
    'email':"bob@bla", 
    'profile':{'id':1, 'role':"admin"}}, 
   {'name':"bob", 
    'age':10, 
    'email':"other mail", 
    'profile':{'id':2, 'role':"dba"},
    'home':"/home/bob"
  }]
```

and I need something to recursively merge entries. If value for an existing given key on the same level is different it appends the value to an array.

```
b = merge(a)
print b
{'name':"bob", 
 'age':10, 
 'email':["bob@bla","other mail"], 
 'profile':{'id':[1,2], 'role'=["admin", "dba"], 'home':"/home/bob"}
```

I wrote this code:

```
def merge(items):
    merged = {}
    for item in items:
        for key in item.keys():
            if key in merged.keys():
                if item[key] != merged[key]:
                    if not isinstance(merged[key], list):
                        merged[key] = [merged[key]]
                    if item[key] not in merged[key]:
                        merged[key].append(item[key])
            else:
                merged[key] = item[key]
    return merged
```

The output is:

```
{'age': 10,
 'email': ['bob@bla', 'other mail'],
 'home': '/home/bob',
 'name': 'bob',
 'profile': [{'id': 1, 'role': 'admin'}, {'id': 2, 'role': 'dba'}]}
```

Which is not what I want.

I can't figure out how to deal with recursion.

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: As I said I'm struggling with this one...

Comment: So you have... nothing? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Well several other topics didn't provide any code either, I'm working on something on my own, if I can make it works I'll post it... I'm looking for advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you iterate over each dictionary in the arguments, then each key and value in each dictionary, you want the following rules:

1. If there is nothing against that key in the output, add the new key and value to the output;
2. If there is a value for that key, and it's the same as the new value, do nothing;
3. If there is a value for that key, and it's a list, `append` the new value to the list;
4. If there is a value for that key, and it's a dictionary, recursively `merge` the new value with the existing dictionary;
5. If there is a value for that key, and it's neither a list nor a dictionary, make the value in the output a list of the current value and the new value.

In code:

```
def merge(*dicts):
    """Recursively merge the argument dictionaries."""
    out = {}
    for dct in dicts:
        for key, val in dct.items():
            try:
                out[key].append(val) # 3.
            except AttributeError:
                if out[key] == val:
                    pass # 2.
                elif isinstance(out[key], dict):
                    out[key] = merge(out[key], val) # 4.
                else:
                    out[key] = [out[key], val] # 5.
            except KeyError:
                out[key] = val # 1.
    return out
```

In use:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(merge(*a))
{'age': 10,
 'email': ['bob@bla', 'other mail'],
 'home': '/home/bob',
 'name': 'bob',
 'profile': {'id': [1, 2], 'role': ['admin', 'dba']}}
```